# Sum of Maclaurin series with centre 0

Tags: taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

Sum the power series,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{nx^n}{n+9}$$

I found my radius of convergence to be 1 and my interval was $-1<x<1$. For end points I checked and I wasn't too sure if they are included in the interval

If they are would the values for which series converges absolutely include the -1 and 1?

---

Comment: Use the fact that $\frac{x^9}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n+8}$ for $x\in(-1,1)$

Comment: I got interval of convergence to be [-1,1] , and how does that fact help with solving my query?

Comment: @HellaAbr For $x=1$ the series doesn't converge.

Comment: That's great and it converges for x=-1

Comment: So interval of convergence is [-1,1)?

Answer (score 0):

For a positive integer $m$
($m=9$ in your case)

$\begin{array}\\
s_m(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{nx^n}{n+m}\\
&=\sum_{n=m}^\infty\frac{(n-m)x^{n-m}}{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=m}^\infty\frac{nx^{n-m}}{n}-\sum_{n=m}^\infty\frac{mx^{n-m}}{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=m}^\infty x^{n-m}-mx^{-m}\sum_{n=m}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n}-mx^{-m}\sum_{n=m}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{n}\\
&=\dfrac1{1-x}-mx^{-m}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{x^{n}}{n})\\
&=\dfrac1{1-x}-mx^{-m}(-\ln(1-x)-\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{x^{n}}{n})\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Ahh, this makes more sense, thank you

Comment: So for what values does my series converge conditionally?

Comment: $x=-1$. It is then an alternating series with decreasing terms.

Comment: So would you say series converges conditionally for x=-1 and absolutely for -1<=×<1?

Comment: Yup. And obviously diverges for $x=1$. Not sure about complex $x$ with $|x|=1$.